# Why is this Bootstrap dropdown not showing the content when clicked?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using `Bootstrap css` and have a dropdown of "Stores", when clicking it the content in the list should display as it does in the Bootstrap documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Can anyone show me what's gone wrong with this?  As far as I'm aware this should work without having the `Bootstrap javascript` included.  Here's an example jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Le43a8o2/

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-light bg-light'>
  <a class='navbar-brand' [routerLink]="['/']">{{pageTitle}}</a>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Stores
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
              </div>
          </div>  
      </li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

Comment: Does it work with js included?

Comment: It literally says in the documentation that bs js is required for it to function: "They’re made interactive with the included Bootstrap dropdown JavaScript plugin. They’re toggled by clicking, not by hovering; this is an intentional design decision.

Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js. Popper.js isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioni...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both `jQuery` and `Bootstrap javascript`. Try to add those 2 resources in your JS Fiddle and see if it works.